# Is it possible for a superclass object to refer a subclass member method which is not inherited?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, java-7

In *dynamic method binding* a superclass reference can only call a subclass method which is inherited and overrode by it. However, the otherwise can be implemented.

```
abstract class in
{
    abstract void print();
}
class a extends in
{
    String name=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("class "+name);
    }
    void print()
    {
        show();
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        in x;
        x = new a();
        x.print();
     }
}
```

Here, it prints successfully

> class a

Also *getClass()* returns the subclass name instead of superclass name as *this* refers to the superclass object in main method.

Comment: Parents cannot know about children.  A developer of a class can't know how their class will be extended by users.

Comment: All `in` knows is that it should have a method called `print()`. All the implementation of that method is taking place inside `a`, which knows all about `a` (so far as its class name and other methods).

Comment: So you mean x.print() is equivalent to new a().print() ? But isn't x a superclass reference ?

Comment: please follow the naming convention by reading http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Sorry. I am aware of the conventions. As this code is not a part of 10k lines of project, I took it lightly. I am only trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parent object reference is just constrained by the methods that it has in its class definition. If those methods are overridden by subclass, and at run time, if the actual object referred by the parent reference is of subclass type, then that overridden method is invoked. It doesn't matter if the overridden method invokes methods that are not originally present in the parent class or accesses the variables that are not present in the parent class.

This is what polymorphism is all about. It is by design meant to be this way as it makes program extension easier in case if we have different specific inheritance hierarchies where the parent class need not know the exact implementation of certain methods and can make things implemented by the subclasses as some sort of contract.

Comment: Thanks this was the ONLY helpful answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Future is unknown** A developer writing a class `A.java` today can never predict in future the names or signatures of the methods which any other developer may include in his class extending `A.java`. Also  such classes may be numerous with each having separate methods.

Base class should never be coupled with its sub classes. It must not care about how the sub classes are implemented.

Although it is not recommended but still if you wish to invoke the method defined in one of the sub class you may do it by *typecasting* like below.

```
public class Parent {
    public class someMethod(){
             if( this instanceof Child1){
                 ((Child1)this).someAdditionalMethod();
             }
     }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent{
     public class someAdditionalMethod(){

    }
}
```